# Lesbian webcomic set in Spain about a rich girl and her family's servant

Tags: identification-request, comics

A long time ago I stumbled on this in a manga site. It was not a manga; this manga site posted comics sometimes. It was set in century Spain (I think?). The main girl is from a rich family who owns a slave or a servant. The main girl also have long blond hair and pale skin. Her love interest in is a maid or slave whom she grew up with who is copper skin and brown curly hair

Comment: What century? Approximately how long ago - 2 years? 10? What language was it in? What style was the art? Was age range was this for? Do you remember any plot details? This seems to be just a pretty vague premise.

Comment: I don't know which century all i know they all wear that old type of dress (maybe 17th? again I'm not sure?) as for the art i can't describe it maybe like this https://tapas.io/series/Black-Magic-/info also for the plot i can't remember all i remember one time both of them ride horses

Comment: Please [edit] details into your question (using correct grammar and formatting) so that they don't get lost in comments

Comment: The [id page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) has a good list of prompts for id request questions. Even little details can help.

Comment: The description reminds me of this hentai anime: Another Lady Innocent:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_Lady_Innocent but I don't know if it is available as comics.

Comment: Not to be rude but that not close

Comment: No offense taken, I just thought it might be worth mentioning as some of the plot details match: rich family, growing together, old type of dress, long blond hair..